# Normal distribution with a very low standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, simulation, monte-carlo, excel

I have a question which the answer is probably obvious, but I couldn't find it so far.

I have a serie of returns which have a standard deviation of 0.0113 and a mean of 0.0009. I want to simulate a large number of these returns, assuming it follows a normal distribution N(0.0009,0.0113).

The problem is, when I run my simulations on Excel, it always returns 0. It seems to be due to the value of the standard deviation, because when I change it to 1 for example, it works.

My question is, can I simulate my returns? Is my standard deviation abnormal?

Comment: Excel shouldn't return 0 for that. Are you using =NORM.INV(RAND(),0.0009,0.0113) ? Maybe the cell isn't large enough to display the full number, excel will round the number displayed to make it fit into the space

Answer (score 1):

Whatever excel thinks it is doing, you can just ask it to simulate normal deviates with mean of zero and standard deviation 1, say, $Z \sim \text{N}(0,1)$ and then yourself calculate $0.0009+0.0113 \cdot Z$ which should work.

Comment: If the problem is due to Excel *formatting* (as suggested above), this won't fix anything because the issue is with how the number is displayed, not how it was computed.